# Trigger Rebuild Is Not Working

Tags: civicontribute, database

I am getting this error " [nativecode=1442 ** Can't update table 'civicrm_contact' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.]" after both migrating my database to another server and upgrading to the 5.19 security upgrade.

I have attempted multiple times to run the trigger rebuild URL for Drupal and to use 
`cv php:eval "CRM_Core_DAO::dropTriggers('civicrm_contact');"
 cv php:eval "CRM_Core_DAO::triggerRebuild('civicrm_contact');"
cv php:eval "CRM_Core_DAO::dropTriggers('civicrm_contribution');"
 cv php:eval "CRM_Core_DAO::triggerRebuild('civicrm_contribution');"`

Any ideas of what else to try I would appreciate it.

Thanks,
Josh

Comment: Have you tried the standard trigger rebuild? https://example.com/civicrm/menu/rebuild?reset=1&triggerRebuild=1

Comment: Yes, I started with that a couple of times before pulling out any code.  Thanks!

Comment: Is there any information about what trigger is causing this error? Do you have logging enabled (civicrm/admin/setting/misc?reset=1)  What do you get when you run the following sql query? "show triggers like 'civicrm_contact%';"

Comment: @Luke Strwart, I do not have logging enabled.  When I do the query you gave me I get one on insert query that is too long to post here. I tried running the drop triggers again to see if it goes away and it does not. Can I safely drop it? Thanks! Happy Thanksgiving!

Comment: Assuming no customisations are involved it's totally fine to manually delete the trigger then run rebuild triggers via the drupal rebuild. 

What is the trigger of the error - can you replicate it? What is the calling function?

Comment: The thing I got to work in the end was to delete the two triggers that were there for on create and on update and then install 5.19.3.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use the API with `cv`, `drush`, or `wp-cli` to call `System.flush` with the parameter `triggers=TRUE`. E.g. `cv api System.flush triggers=TRUE`.